# Automator : Every time I paste an action, I get : “AppleScript Error; can’t make «class” until Automator becomes unresponsive

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Running MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

I'm new to Automator and AppleScript. I'm trying to write a Workflow/Service that scans a Microsoft Word document to replace dozens of words with abbreviations. As such, my Automator Workflow just consists of the pre-loaded action "Find and Replace Text in Word Documents," repeated dozens of times. The pre-loaded action comes w/ the Microsoft Word icon, so it's not a generic text action.

This is the error popup I get :

[image: Mac screenshot of the error popup "AppleScript Error; Can't make «class"]

So after I drag & drop the first "Find and Replace Text", I just copy & paste it repeatedly. But each paste prompts an error popup :

> Applescript Error ; Can't make «class

But after I dismiss the popup by clicking OK, the pasted action still runs normally w/ a green checkmark. However, after pasting the same action 100 times & dismissing that error popup 100 times, Automator inevitably freezes & becomes "Not Responding", so I never complete & save a finished Workflow/Service.

My workflow's first action is "Bring Word Documents to Front"; then it's just copies & pastes of "Find and Replace....". Am I getting the error because my workflow is missing a few opening actions like "set" or "get"?

How do I avoid Automator freezing & becoming unresponsive? Or is that just an inevitable risk of running the same action 100+ times?

Comment: Please don't crosspost. If you weren't getting any responses then consider editing the question for focus or clarity.

Comment: I didn't mean to crosspost; I couldn't find the 1st time I asked this question by clicking on my profile

Comment: It looks like it was deleted. I would still consider editing your post. Either way, it's missing useful information. I can't copy and paste workflow actions so I'm not sure what you're doing. There is a 'duplicate' command which you can access with a right-click. That error doesn't look like it's related to the issue you're having so what else is going on? What is your end goal here? What happens if your workflow has two 'find and replace' actions rather than 100? Anyway, just some random thoughts.